# SQL Server connection string with EF

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I just converted a MySQL database to SQL Server. I'm complete new to SQL Server, I want to use it with Entity Framework 4, so I shouldn't be a biggie.

I think I don't get the concepts about objects in DB and so on. In SQL Server Mgmt Studio I can execute this query

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
  FROM [db].[dbo].[mytable]
```

And it works fine, however if I use this connection string

```
Data Source=MYPC-PC\;Integrated Security=SSPI;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=60;Connect Timeout=30
```

The query will execute fine, but it will exclude the [db], so it will not return any row. This is the query from Entity Framework.

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
  FROM [dbo].[mytable]
```

If I change my connection string to include a Database like this

```
Data Source=MYPC-PC\;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=db;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=60;Connect Timeout=30
```

I get this error

> *There is already an object named 'MyTable' in the database.*

But there is only one table called `Table`. I have no idea of the concepts behind this. What am I doing wrong? I'm using SQL Server 2012

## Update 1

I use code first.

```
        var result = db.MyTable.Where(x => x.Prop == Prop)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Something)
            .Take(10);

        var data = result.ToList();
```

My DbContext class

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    
     public Context()
    : base("Context")
  {
    // Get the ObjectContext related to this DbContext
    var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

    // Sets the command timeout for all the commands
    objectContext.CommandTimeout = 12000;
  }

    public DbSet<Models.MyTable> MyTable{ get; set; }


}
```

And in web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Context" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="connectionString"  />
```

Comment: table is a keyword, can you use any other name?

Comment: Hm, it was just an excample. I updated the question

Comment: Which EF approach are you using? Code-first? Database-first with a visual model?

Comment: can you post your code please.

Comment: Updated with code. I use code first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table `MyTable` already exists in the database before first migration. So you can just delete this table and then it will be recreated at first application run.

**EDIT:**
If you don't want to remove your table and if you use at least EF 4.3 then
run from the Console `Add-Migration InitialMigration -IgnoreChanges`
and then run `Update-Database`

Comment: Ok, but MyTable contains a lot of data, so I don't want to delete it. Will the database be marked as migrated? Or can I force it do be marked so it just continue?

Comment: But that's not going to work into my production server. Couse I don't have Visual Studio on that. How can I solve that?

Comment: For the production server it's better to disable automatic migration by setting `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false` in your code.

Comment: Also you can copy `__MigrationHistory` table from your development server to the production server.